# How do I store multiple values inside of an array under specific circumstances such as in a multiple-choice program

Tags: arrays, c

How do I assign multiple values inside of an array under specific conditions such as a multiple-choice program? To give context, I am currently making a program wherein it will ask the user to play a multiple-question game where you can choose the question that you want to answer regardless of order. The premise is that for example question number one is worth 10 points. If you answer it correctly you get 10 points if not you get -10 points, and that is where my problem starts what I'm trying to do is I am trying to put the points inside of the array. For example, if I am correct in question number one 10 will be stored in the array, but if I answered wrong the array will then store -10. Now my first question is how do I store the points inside of an array? Lastly, is how do I add all the elements that is inside of the array?

Displayed below is the source code that I am currently working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    
    int num, points, Score[3], corr;
    char code, ans;
    
    do
    {
    printf("Enter code: \n");
    scanf(" %c", &code);
    
    switch(code)
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        
        printf("Enter amount: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        
        switch(num)
        {
            case 1:
            
            printf("Which of the following is the capital of the USA \n");
            printf("A.  Washington, D.C.\n");
            printf("B. California \n");
            printf("C. Texas\n");
            printf("D. New York\n");
            printf("Enter answer: \n");
            scanf(" %c", &ans);
            
            if(ans == 'a' || ans == 'A')
            {
                printf("Correct\n");
                points = 100;
                corr++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Incorrect Answer!\n");
                points = -100;
            }
            break;
            
            case 2:
            
            printf("3 + 3 = ?\n");
            printf("A. 6\n");
            printf("B. 9\n");
            printf("C. 5\n");
            printf("D. 3\n");
            printf("Enter answer: \n");
            printf(" %c", &ans);
            
            if(ans == 'a' || ans == 'A')
            {
                printf("Correct\n");
                points = 200;
                corr++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Incorrect Answer!\n");
                points = -200;
            }
            
            break;
            
        }
        
        break;
        
        
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            
            printf("Enter amount: ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            
             switch(num)
            {
            
            case 1:
            
            printf("3 + 5 = ?\n");
            printf("A. 6\n");
            printf("B. 8 \n");
            printf("C. 5\n");
            printf("D. 3\n");
            printf("Enter answer: \n");
            scanf(" %c", &ans);
            
            if(ans == 'b' || ans == 'B')
            {
                printf("Correct\n");
                points = 200;
                corr++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Incorrect Answer!\n");
                points = -200;
            }
            
            break;
             }
        
        break;
        
    }
    
    }while(corr < 4);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the usual way for constructing an array but it keeps on showing segmentation fault and showing  garbage values.

Comment: There at least following problems: You dont initialize `corr`, the initial value of local variables is undetermined. And `printf(" %c", &ans);` should be `printf(" %c", ans);`. And you don't store anything in any array. That being said, it's unclear what the program is supposed to do, please [edit] and show a simple example of input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: You should as well check the return value of `scanf` to catch invalid input. Note, too, that not all kind of invalid input can be caught this way (e.g. you detect non-numeric input on scanning numbers, but you don't if they are out of valid range for your problem).

Comment: I'd actually redesign all of your code and base the questions already on arrays! You'd need a `struct Task` with members `char const* question`, another array for the answers and finally a variable for the points *available* (optional, if these can vary per question) and a variable for the points *achieved*. You don't need such a large switch/case then, just access the right index...

Comment: Such a re-designed programme might look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/EdGfo5q4h) – suppose it illustrates the idea itself (note, too, how all the data necessary – apart from some simple IO strings – is located at one single place!) just as well as how to operate on arrays. Just some advice: Have a close look, understand how it works (ask, if need be!) and re-write on your own from scratch! If you just copied and pasted for perhaps a school assignment – not my business, it would be you not learning anything from ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store in the same element different types you need to have a struct with a member indicating the type of the element and `union` with the actual value as elements of this array.

Example:

```
typedef enum
{
    INT,
    CHARPTR,
    DOUBLE,
    UNKNOWN,
}TYPE_t;

typedef struct
{
    TYPE_t type;
    union
    {
        int i;
        char *cp;
        double d;
    };
}ARRAY_ELEM_t;


int main(void)
{
    ARRAY_ELEM_t array[3] = {
        {.type = INT, .i = 540},
        {.type = CHARPTR, .cp = "hello world"},
        {.type = DOUBLE, .d = M_PI},
    };

    for(size_t index = 0; index < 3; index++)
    {
        switch(array[index].type)
        {
            case INT:
                printf("array[%zu] - INT = %d\n", index, array[index].i);
                break;
            case CHARPTR:
                printf("array[%zu] - char * = '%s'\n", index, array[index].cp);
                break;
            case DOUBLE:
                printf("array[%zu] - INT = %f\n", index, array[index].d);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qodG3ecxG

If you want to store a different number of elements of different types in one array you can use flexible array members.

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t nelements;
    ARRAY_ELEM_t array[];
}room_t;


room_t *initroom(size_t nelements)
{
    room_t *room = malloc(sizeof(*room) + nelements * sizeof(room -> array[0]));
    if(room) room -> nelements = nelements;
    return room;
}

int main(void)
{
    room_t *rooms[5];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(size_t index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        rooms[index] = initroom(rand() % 50);
    }

    for(size_t index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        if(rooms[index]) printf("room %zu can hold %zu elements\n", index, rooms[index] -> nelements);
    }
    /* free when not needed */
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Wc1eW8r8f